# Removed Visuals show up in the Live Visual Tree

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, c++-cx

I have some code on these lines.

```
void init() {
    UIElement = new UserControl();
    auto hostVisual = Windows::UI::Xaml::Hosting::ElementCompositionPreview::GetElementVisual(UIElement);
    auto compositor = hostVisual->Compositor;
    auto visualRoot = compositor->CreateContainerVisual();
    Windows::UI::Xaml::Hosting::ElementCompositionPreview::SetElementChildVisual(UIElement, container);
}

void update() {
    auto hostVisual = Windows::UI::Xaml::Hosting::ElementCompositionPreview::GetElementVisual(UIElement);
    auto visualTreeRoot = dynamic_cast<Windows::UI::Composition::ContainerVisual ^>
        (Windows::UI::Xaml::Hosting::ElementCompositionPreview::GetElementChildVisual(view().nativeView()));
    visualTreeRoot->Children->RemoveAll();
    auto spriteVisual1 = visualTreeRoot ->Compositor->CreateSpriteVisual();
    : //Set properties like size, color of the SpriteVisual
    : 
    visualTreeRoot->Children->InsertAtTop(spriteVisual1);
    :
    :
    visualTreeRoot->Children->InsertAtTop(spriteVisual2);
}
```

Now my expectation from the code is that with every update, all the children from the root `ContainerVisual` should be removed and new ones added every time. But the Live Visual Tree (under `Debug->Window->Live Visual Tree`) shows something different like this

[image].

The stranger part is that only two of these actually show up valid properties in the `Live Property Explorer` as

[image: Property Explorer Valid]

while the other ones simply show up empty as

[image: Property Explorer InValid]

Is this a bug in my code or in VS that doesn't excise the *removed* visuals from the tree? If not, what else do I need to do?

P.S. Interestingly, calling `Close()` on a `Visual` throws a compilation error, despite it being mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositionobject.close?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Composition_CompositionObject_Close)! I'd resorted to the `Close()` API suspecting I was somehow leaking resources. This is the error:

> error C2039: 'Close': is not a member of
> 'Windows::UI::Composition::Visual'

Comment: I also wrote code based on your expectation to test the **Live Visual Tree** and the **Live Visual Tree** does not show the deletion of visuals. The question may be located in Visual Studio. You could try to go to **Send Feedback** which locates the upper right corner of Visual Studio, then select **Report a Problem** option.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @YanGu-MSFT! Will do as suggested.

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT One more thing, any thoughts on why the document is at variance with the actual compiler? Is it an oversight on the documentation or is there some other nuance to this issue.

Comment: Also created an issue on the VS team [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Removed-Visuals-show-up-in-the-Live-Visu/1371481)